# unity C#: find something in a json file from the web

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I just want to find a certain property in a pretty long JSON file that I got via this [API](https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=sonic&limit=1). Just want to get the movie URL

```
{
  "data" :{
      "movies": [
           {
           "url" : [ENTER URL HERE]
           }
       ]  
    }
}
```

just want to get that URL and put it in a variable programmatically for opening in a browser and maybe display in the app

Script that gets the code and makes the json readable to humans:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Serialization;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 
using System.IO;


public class GETFromYTS : MonoBehaviour
{
    [FormerlySerializedAs("URL")] public string url;

    void Start()
    {
        // A correct website page.
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url));
       //Application.OpenURL(url);

    }



    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
            int page = pages.Length - 1;

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {

                string json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(webRequest.downloadHandler.text).ToString();
                Debug.Log(json);


            }    
        }
    }
}
```

using Jetbrains Rider as IDE

the full json for extra info:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "status_message": "Query was successful",
    "data": {
        "movie_count": 1,
        "limit": 1,
        "page_number": 1,
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": 15813,
                "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/movie\/sonic-the-hedgehog-2020",
                "imdb_code": "tt3794354",
                "title": "Sonic the Hedgehog",
                "title_english": "Sonic the Hedgehog",
                "title_long": "Sonic the Hedgehog (2020)",
                "slug": "sonic- the-hedgehog-2020",
                "year": 2020,   
                "rating": 6.6,
                "runtime": 99,
                "genres": [
                    "Action",
                    "Adventure",
                    "Comedy",
                    "Family",
                    "Sci-Fi"
                ],
                "summary": "Based on the global blockbuster videogame franchise from Sega, SONIC THE HEDGEHOG tells the story of the world's speediest hedgehog as he embraces his new home on Earth. In this live-action adventure comedy, Sonic and his new best friend Tom (James Marsden) team up to defend the planet from the evil genius Dr. Robotnik (Jim Carrey) and his plans for world domination. The family-friendly film also stars Tika Sumpter and Ben Schwartz as the voice of Sonic.",
                "description_full": "Based on the global blockbuster videogame franchise from Sega, SONIC THE HEDGEHOG tells the story of the world's speediest hedgehog as he embraces his new home on Earth. In this live-action adventure comedy, Sonic and his new best friend Tom (James Marsden) team up to defend the planet from the evil genius Dr. Robotnik (Jim Carrey) and his plans for world domination. The family-friendly film also stars Tika Sumpter and Ben Schwartz as the voice of Sonic.",
                "synopsis": "Based on the global blockbuster videogame franchise from Sega, SONIC THE HEDGEHOG tells the story of the world's speediest hedgehog as he embraces his new home on Earth. In this live-action adventure comedy, Sonic and his new best friend Tom (James Marsden) team up to defend the planet from the evil genius Dr. Robotnik (Jim Carrey) and his plans for world domination. The family-friendly film also stars Tika Sumpter and Ben Schwartz as the voice of Sonic.",
                "yt_trailer_code": "szby7ZHLnkA",
                "language": "English",
                "mpa_rating": "PG",
                "background_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/sonic_the_hedgehog_2020\/background.jpg",
                "background_image_original": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/sonic_the_hedgehog_2020\/background.jpg",
                "small_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/sonic_the_hedgehog_2020\/small-cover.jpg",
                "medium_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/sonic_the_hedgehog_2020\/medium-cover.jpg",
                "large_cover_image": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/assets\/images\/movies\/sonic_the_hedgehog_2020\/large-cover.jpg",
                "state": "ok",
                "torrents": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/torrent\/download\/77EFB6CF3336FCB8FC3FC67A222F548FF88BF00C",
                        "hash": "77EFB6CF3336FCB8FC3FC67A222F548FF88BF00C",
                        "quality": "720p",
                        "type": "web",
                        "seeds": 4441,
                        "peers": 736,
                        "size": "911.23 MB",
                        "size_bytes": 955493908,
                        "date_uploaded": "2020-03-08 19:31:51",
                        "date_uploaded_unix": 1583692311
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yts.mx\/torrent\/download\/F3ACFD3979CC1A30CC7F312673CED688CE78CE77",
                        "hash": "F3ACFD3979CC1A30CC7F312673CED688CE78CE77",
                        "quality": "1080p",
                        "type": "web",
                        "seeds": 6737,
                        "peers": 1071,
                        "size": "1.65 GB",
                        "size_bytes": 1771674010,
                        "date_uploaded": "2020-03-08 21:15:14",
                        "date_uploaded_unix": 1583698514
                    }
                ],
                "date_uploaded": "2020-03-08 19:31:51",
                "date_uploaded_unix": 1583692311
            }
        ]
    },
    "@meta": {
        "server_time": 1586605584,
        "server_timezone": "CET",
        "api_version": 2,
        "execution_time": "0 ms"
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: that is the script to get the JSON and display it in the log. just want to sort through the JSON and get that URL

Comment: So what? Use a json deserializer and plopp `webRequest.downloadHandler.text` into it, then look for the URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp) or [how can I parse json with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: [https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)  etc.

Comment: half does, now how do I search it programmatically? have not found a satisfying answer, VERY new to unity and C#

Comment: ok, I'm trying to do something with the docs link, hope it works.

Comment: please see my edits for more info and the full json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the Unity's built-in [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) static class? Just declare the shape of your data with a class and convert the JSON with it.

```
[Serializable]
public class Movie 
{
   public string url;
   public string title;
   public string title_english;

   // Include every needed field
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public Movie[] movies;
}

[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public Data data;
}

// ... everywhere you need 

Response res = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(json);

for (int i = 0; i < res.data.movies.Length; i++)
{
   Debug.Log(res.data.movies[i].url);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I just found out about simpleJSON, its amazing for what I need to do, and the json2csharp webpage did what you just did. thanks for the response and I'll make this the answer.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.